# How to include url in default spring servlet exception logger

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When an exception occurs, a message is logged as:

`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is <the real exception>`

How can I modify this message to include the request url that caused the exception?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this log error is shown only if the exception is not resolved by spring, so it propagates up to tomcat's `StandardWrapperValve.java` that logs the error:

```
catch (ServletException e) {
    Throwable rootCause = StandardWrapper.getRootCause(e);
    if (!(rootCause instanceof ClientAbortException)) {
        container.getLogger().error(sm.getString(
                "standardWrapper.serviceExceptionRoot",
                wrapper.getName(), context.getName(), e.getMessage()),
                rootCause);
    }
    throwable = e;
    exception(request, response, e);
}
```

I have no control over tomcat's logged message so I've created a fallback spring `HandlerExceptionResolver` that replaces the last exception resolver `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`, preventing the exception to propagate to tomcat:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers( List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers ) {
        resolvers.stream()
                .filter( r -> r instanceof DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver ).findAny()
                .ifPresent( resolvers::remove );
        resolvers.add( new FallbackHandlerExceptionResolver() );
    }

    private static class FallbackHandlerExceptionResolver extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( FallbackHandlerExceptionResolver.class );

        @Override
        public ModelAndView resolveException( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex ) {
            ModelAndView mv = super.resolveException( request, response, handler, ex );
            if (mv == null) {
                try {
                    log.error( String.format( "Error %s %s", request.getMethod(), UrlUtils.getRequestUrl( request ) ), ex );
                    response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
                    return new ModelAndView(); //skip next handlers
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error( "Error sending response error", e );
                }
            }
            return mv;
        }
    }
}
```